# clError in apache mod_cluster

Tags: jboss, load-balancing, apache

I can't access mod_cluster-manager and I'm getting the following error on my error.log in apache

```
[Wed Jan 16 17:20:13 2013] [warn] module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping 
[Wed Jan 16 17:20:13 2013] [notice] Advertise initialized for process 2410 
[Wed Jan 16 17:20:13 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) mod_cluster/1.2.0.Final PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.8 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Wed Jan 16 17:27:22 2013] [error] proxy: CLUSTER: (balancer://mycluster). All workers are in error state 
[Wed Jan 16 17:27:23 2013] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /favicon.ico. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

I configured jboss Standalone mode to enable mod_cluster. I added the following lines in their respective sections in standalone-ha.xml

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.modcluster"/>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.0">
            <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" advertise-security-key="secret"/>
        </subsystem>
```

I downloaded the following modules : 
    mod_slotmem.so
    mod_manager.so
    mod_proxy_cluster.so
    mod_advertise.so

in http://downloads.jboss.org/mod_cluster//1.1.0.Final/mod_cluster-1.1.0.Final-linux2-x64-so.tar.gz then put it in usr/lib/apache2/modules.

I have set the following in mod_cluster.load in /etc/apache2/mods-available.

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule slotmem_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_advertise.so
```

I have set the following in mod_cluster.conf

```
CreateBalancers 1
<IfModule manager_module>
    Listen 127.0.0.1:8082
    ManagerBalancerName mycluster

     <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8082>
        KeepAliveTimeout 300
        MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
        AdvertiseFrequency 5
        ServerAdvertise On
        <Location />
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Location>
     </VirtualHost>
  </IfModule>
```

I enable the module by executing
$ sudo a2enmod mod_cluster

And lastly, I have set the following in jboss in /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerAdmin info@domain.de
    ServerName  comitdev2
    ServerAlias comitdev2
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster
    ProxyPreserveHost On
      <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from All
    </Location>

    <Location /mod_cluster-manager>
      SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
      Order deny,allow
      #Deny from all
      Allow from 127.0.0
   </Location>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Lastly, I disabled the 000-default site and enabled the jboss site

Everytime I access the localhost I get Service Temporarily Unavailable.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Please tag more carefully. This is not [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering, a data mining technique). You probably meant to use the tag [tag:load-balancing].

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can see mod_cluster/1.2.0.Final in your log whereas you state you used mod_cluster-1.1.0.Final-linux2-x64-so.tar.gz, how come?

Why do you use CreateBalancers 1 and ProxyPass while you don't do anything special in ProxyPass? The setting seems to be correct though. I would suggest to try to run with CreateBalancers 1 and ProxyPass commented out in order to narrow down the error search space :-)

Anyhow, try this:

**mod_cluster.conf**

```
# MOD_CLUSTER_ADDS
<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 127.0.0.1:8082 
  ManagerBalancerName mycluster

  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8082>
    <Location />
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     #Just for testing, of course...
     Allow from all
    </Location>

    KeepAliveTimeout 300
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    AdvertiseFrequency 5
    #AdvertiseSecurityKey secret
    #This is important, see docs...
    EnableMCPMReceive

    <Location /mcm>
       SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       #Just for testing, of course...
       Allow from all
    </Location>

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**http.conf**

```
# This must be disabled for mod_cluster to work properly!
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so

# mod_cluster ifself
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so
```

**as7**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1">
    <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp" />
</subsystem>
```

**NOTE:** I have *urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1*, and you should use more recent AS7 as well. Schema 1.0 is quite obsolete.

If this dead-simple setup works for you, then add your ProxyPass back and let's see whether it is the cause of your troubles or not.

HTH